# Override valueOf method cause diffrence on console.log(+[])?

Tags: javascript

when read **The Definitive Guide**,
[image]

so I want to check whether it operate like that

before I override the method
`console.log(+[])  //0`

but after

```
var proto = [].__proto__.__proto__
var valueOf = proto.valueOf
proto.valueOf = function(){
debugger;
valueOf.apply(this,arguments);
}
console.log(+[])  //NaN
```

who could tell me where is my fault?

Comment: You don't return anything. `+undefined` -> `NaN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the result of the wrapped function.

```
proto.valueOf = function(){
    debugger;
    return valueOf.apply(this,arguments);
//  ^^^^^^
};
```

Btw, you should really avoid overwriting `Object.prototype.valueOf`. Just give the object you're testing with its own method.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `return` statement:

```
var proto = [].__proto__.__proto__
var valueOf = proto.valueOf
proto.valueOf = function(){
  debugger;
  // You have to add a return statement here.
  return valueOf.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

And yes, not a good idea to override `__proto__` of `Object`s.